# minimum application size for my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am developing a application which contains many images which appear on different buttons click and has an mp3 file too..When i checked the size of my .app file it is around 6.8 mb which i think might be too large?? is there any way i can reduce the size of my .app file though i think reducing the size of my images(already around 15kb) wont be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6.8mb is fine and is small enough that people can downloaded it over 3G (the limit is 20Mb; you need wifi if it's more)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is sales! On any app you do now or in the future you will want to keep the total size under 20mb.

Think about how many users want to "instinctively buy" your app. They saw a friend with your app and want to download it right then and there, but ohh wait... cant do it till ya get home! LOST SALE - More than likely that person will forget by the time they get home.

In your case 6.8mb is nothing compared to many apps that are games. I've seen 200 - 300mb apps that take a while to download on wifi. (WSOP Poker , Gamebox)

Good Luck my friend!